# Safely quit application before a certain amount of time is reached?

Tags: php

I have a script running every 10 minutes in a cron and would like the script to quit after 9 minutes to stop any overlapping.

The script is running a foreach loop, polling an inbox and running a series of functions on every message in the inbox.

I know I can use set_time_limit but looking for a more elegant way to exit the script at the end of a loop if the script has been running for more than 9 minutes.

Comment: No matter how you do it, aborting your job before it has finished will result in some of the content of your inbox being left unprocessed. Either you need to extend the time between executions, or find a way to speed things up.

Comment: Why don't you set your cron to run every minute and check for a lock on the currently running php file and it will only run again if the lock does not exist.

Comment: Why don't you set a variable when the script runs and change that variable when the script finishes. You can then check your variable to see if your script is running or not, and write a condition.

Comment: At the beginning of your script: `$startTime = time()`. Inside your foreach: `if (time() - $startTime > 60 * 9) { break; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to turn off a job half way of what it is doing (unless there's a failure in the code and you want to abort... but that's not the everyday's use case)

You need a singleton management. For example, turn a token to "running" when starting, and then turn it to "not running" when quiting (don't forget error management). So when the 2nd iteration of the job tries to overlap, testing the token allows you to know whether or not it should run.

You could use a database token, or a file token etc.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your **need**, your need is to prevent parallel running of the same script. The **right** solution would be to implement a locking or queue mechanism, so same script won't run in parallel.

U can use file | db | memory lock. File is the simplest.
1. Check for the lock file existence
2. If exists
3.     wait X seconds -> goto 1
4. Create the file
5. Continue your script
...
...
6. End of script -> delete file.

Put this logic in every script that uses this lock.
U can also not create/delete the file but rather modify the content in it (say toggle between 1 and 0)

Comment: I like this idea but unsure of how to implement this. First idea would be to create a file/cookie at the start of the script and then remove at end. If cookie exists at time of script run then exit. Would you suggest this this is the way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @Franco local file not cookie.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really the way to do things, but if you must, here's a suggestion:

At the top of your code note the start time, then check at the end of each iteration:

```
$start_time = time();

{start execution loop}

// Do your stuff here

if ((time() - $start_time) > (9*60)) {   // execution time in seconds
  exit;
}

{go around again}
```

You'd really be better finding a way to ensure that the code completes in the available time, or preventing a second instance from starting before the first has finished.